# Font Awesome with react, how to display an icon passed down as a prop

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I use FontAwesome for icons in my React Project and this is how I usually display the icons

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={stroopwafel} />
```

where I have a components library where all the necessary components are imported from FA library and exported to the underlying project

Now there is a situation where the icon names is passed down from parent component as a prop

```
<AccordionPanel id='favFood' title='Fav Food' icon='stroopwafel'>
  ....
</AccordionPanel>
```

Now my child AccordionPanel component needs to display it

```
const { id, title, icon} = this.props

     <Panel.Heading>
         <Panel.Title toggle>
            <Icon icon={icon} color='orange'/> 
         </Panel.Title>
     </Panel.Heading>
```

But this does not seem to work. Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome icons need prefix: `<i class="fas fa-stroopwafel"></i>`
This is from the latest FA: https://fontawesome.com/icons/stroopwafel?style=solid
You might need different prefix if you use older version of FA.
Try to pass "fas fa-stroopwafel" instead of "stroopwafel" as icon prop.